# VoIP - need setup ip network without SIP operator

Tags: networking, voip, gateway

Need to make next one: for ex i'm now in UAE, but i need to make a call to my girlfriend who is in Ukraine. I need to find the way how can i make the connection to my home router and make the call from VoIP gateway using my standard phone network in Ukraine.

I have some imagination about this, to do like this:

Connect to router or VoIP gateway (how? soft?) using inet -> Gateway make a call using standard phone line in my country.

Any ideas? Best practice? What devices i need to make this?

Pay attention that i don't want to use any SIP providers.

Thats a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: I'm under impression, that **any** SIP-usage is illegal in UAE (may be wrong)

Is "home router" router in UA or in UAE? (I suppose it must be UA in order to perform VoIP-termination, which is, BTW, illegal in Ukraine).

Well, in any case, technically (forget about law for now) functional version will be

- Active internet-connection in your ua-home, which have also landline phone
- VOIP-gate, which have at least one **FXO**-port (*not FXS*) (will be connected to landline) - I can suggest to see at some Linksys (I know, they **can** gate VoIP<->PSTN)
- Soft-phone at your side in UAE
- RTFM-RTFM-RTFM, grok dialplans of Linksys (big headache), can't help with it
- After all, you will be able perform direct SIP-call to UA-device, gate to PSTN and call local numbers as local phone

Just note: SIP-account from any SIP-operator and call to UA-landline directly will be a lot more easier and faster way

Comment: VoIp is absolutely legal in Ukraine (im' living in UA) :) UAE was just the location example. I need this cause i make a lot of long trips during the year and want to have cost free way for making calls. In this way i don't want to have any agent between me and my home phone :) your suggestion looks good, thanks a lot!

Comment: VOIP, not **VOIP-Termination to PSTN**

Comment: SIP operator (with secured by TLS voice-connection, if you are *so* paranoid) is, from my POV, good choice anyway and produce less "points of failures"

Comment: i dont care about security of connection. just want to have the solution that i can manage by myself

Comment: Solution, that you *can manage* and *manage*: 1. Run own SIP-server, create accounts for you and your girlfriend 2. Make a gift to girlfriend: Android-phone with installed SIP-phone, configured to use her account from your SIP-server and your SIP ID, added to addressbook 3. Configure own softphone 4. Call 5. Have fun

Comment: great solution, but require dedicated server. But i should think about this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1842/discussion-between-evgeniy-labusnkiy-and-lazy-badger)

Comment: **cont'ed** in chat